How to unpin channel from timeline
I noticed that one object always appears in the timeline even though it isn't selected. I tried toggling the pic icon of the object in the channel space but it keeps appearing even when I select other object.
I've restarted blender hoping it was just a glitch, but it's still happening. Am I missing something.
As you can see here, the object on the left is selected and appears in the timeline as expected, but the one on the right, despite being unselected and having the channel pin disabled, still appears nonetheless
Can someone help me. Thanks


Do you have "Only show selected" checked on the Timeline View menu?

Yeah I do. I toggled it and it's still the same outcome

Hello could you please share your file?

Sure. Here's a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jKLXSfl96v-Zb438JykzLPaE79DJo1nb/view?usp=drive_link

weird I can't see any keyframe, the 2 actions seem to be empty

Ohh, the keyframes are at about from 1609-1728

oh yes you're right, sorry, yes that's weird

Any luck so far?
